# Passing a unique id to a function in a loop in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and facing a problem while calling a function in a loop. I am iterating over a map and calling a function every time with a unique id passed into it. But what i observed is that the same id i.e. the id of the last element in the map is passed to the function instead of corresponding ids of the elements of the map.
Here, is the code snippet. Thanks in advance.

```
    render() {

      let items = _.map(data, (item, index) => {
      return (
              <ListItem
                key={item.ID}
                divider
              > 
              <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                  <Menu
                   id="long-menu"
                  >
                  <MenuItem>
                       <IconButton onClick={() => this.props.delete(item.ID)} >
                           Delete entry<DeleteIcon />
                       </IconButton>
                   </MenuItem>
                 </Menu>
               <ListItemSecondaryAction>
            </ListItem>
          )
        })      
         return (
          <Fragment>
            <List>
             {items}
             </List>
          </Fragment>
         )
   }
```

Comment: try native JS map() function instead of underscore.js's map

Answer (score 2):

Try and create a scoped instance with `let`:

```
render () {
  const items = _.map(data, (item, index) => {
    let id = item.ID;
    return (
      ...
        <IconButton onClick={() => this.props.delete(id)} >
      ...
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense, just assigning the value to a new variable wouldn't solve the problem, right? Moreover, the `let id` will be executed on every loop affecting performance and memory usage

Comment: @Ajay It makes perfect sense for this particular use case, you want it to be set every loop because you want each id to be unique

Answer (score 0):

You could restructure your component by creating a new component as your list item

**ListItem.js**

```
function ListItem (props) {
  const {item, delete} = props

  return (
    <ListItemSecondaryAction>
      <Menu id="long-menu">
      <MenuItem>
           <IconButton onClick={() => delete(item.ID)} >
              Delete entry<DeleteIcon />
           </IconButton>
       </MenuItem>
     </Menu>
   <ListItemSecondaryAction>
  )
}
```

**MyList.js**

```
import ListItem from './ListItem'
...

render () {
  ...
  return (
    <List>
      _.map(data, (item, index) => (
        <ListItem key={item.ID} delete={delete} item={item}/>
      ))
    </List>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should bind the value to the function:

```
<IconButton onClick={this.props.delete.bind(this, item.ID)} >
```

Comment: but I think binding is needed only when we do not use '=>'. Since i am using '=>' while calling the function, I think it should not be needed

Comment: Can you share `this.props.delete()` implementation too.

Comment: @vartika Yes if you use arrow function but then your do not need binding but there you use case won't be served. Also why would you need call one function(i.e. arrow function) which in turn calls to your function?

Comment: The delete function opens up a popup confirming whether the user is sure to delete or not. If the user clicks on 'OK', then another function is called which in turns makes an API call and deleted the entry with the matching id               
   delete: (id) => {
      dispatch(openDeleteDialog(id))
    }

Comment: In the above comment ^ , Where does `searchId` come from?

Comment: it was a typing mistake, it is 'id' and not 'searchId'

Comment: @vartika Have you tried this? This should solve your issue and i think it's better approach too.

Comment: @vartika [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-or-callback) is the document for the recommended methods to bind the function as a event handler + pass the arguments to it. Note the use of `.bind()` function there.